# htaccess won't load images and css

Tags: .htaccess

I recently changed the directory to one of my websites and wrote a rule within the htaccess file to handle the redirect. However, the css and images fail to load now.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\.*)$ http://www.myDomain.com/temp_site/$1 [R=301,L]
```

#### EDIT:

Some of the files that don't work are

> http://www.myDomain.com/css/style.css
>   http://www.myDomain.com/images/me.jpg
>   http://www.myDomain.com/about.php

Comment: What are some of the URLs that aren't working?

Comment: What do you want the rewrite rule to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule !^temp_site/ /temp_site%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is close, but the url is now...
http://www.mydomain.com/temp_site/myPage.htm

anyway I can get www.mydomain.com/myPage.htm

Comment: Got the desired affect by removing the R=301.

Thanks